# Creating Core data objects using Reflection

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, reflection, nsmanagedobject

I am creating objects in a core data database. My approach has been to create a category for each managed object and have a create method. This is working fine. However I have around 6 classes where the code is pretty much identical apart from the Class name.

Therefore I thought it would be better to have one class that passes in the name of the class being created and use:

```
 Class classType = NSClassFromString(className);
```

so that I have access to that class type.

When calling;

```
  NSDictionary *attributes = [[classType entity] attributesByName];
```

I get the following warning:

> 'Instance method 'entity' is being used on 'Class' which is not in the root class'.

**Here is my code:**

Header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface GenericObjectCreation : NSManagedObject

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)createNewObjectWithData:(NSDictionary *)data
                                   className:(NSString *)className
                         inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "GenericObjectCreation.h"

@implementation GenericObjectCreation

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)createNewObjectWithData:(NSDictionary *)data
                                   className:(NSString *)className
                      inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Class classType = NSClassFromString(className);

    classType = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *nexplanons = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    for (id key in data) {

        NSDictionary *element = [data objectForKey:key];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:className];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"organisationCode = %@", element[@"organisationCode"]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if ([result count] > 0) {
            classType = result[0];
        }
        if (![result count]) {
           classType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:context];
    }

        // Loop through attributes on
        NSDictionary *attributes = [[classType entity] attributesByName];
        for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
            id value = [element objectForKey:attribute];
            if (value == nil) {
            continue;
        }
        [classType setValue:value forKey:attribute];
    }
    [nexplanons setObject:classType forKey:element[@"organisationCode"]];
}
[context save:nil];

return nexplanons;

}

@end
```

It seems like this should be possible and would remove a lot of code from my project which would be nice. Any help will be much appreciated.

As a side question, is this called reflection?

Comment: Your issue is an objective-c issue - `Class` doesn't contain the selector `entity`. Unrelated to your question, Core Data and KVO already do a lot of runtime trickery, which given the approach you are attempting may lead you into problems later.

Comment: Thanks for the response. With that I have decided to leave things as they are.